# MySQL JSON пересортировка ключей объекта

Tags: php, mysql, sql, сортировка

Как не допускать сортировку ключей объекта при записи в бд MySQL JSON? Есть много вещей где сохранение порядка ключей очень важно..Например другие SQL бд, сохраняют эту позицию, взять к примеру MongoDB, так с чего же MySQL не сохраняет?

Comment: `"Есть много вещей где сохранение порядка ключей очень важно."` Можно пару примеров для общего развития? А то у меня воображение что-то отказывает.

Comment: ну к примеру JSON схемы для форм. где конструкция состоит из составления порядка ключей.
http://json-schema.org/examples.html
использование на деле
http://brutusin.org/json-forms/

Comment: думал postgre предлагает что-то подобное, но оказывается там даже всё еще хуже.. неужели для этого использовать что-то по типу MongoDB..

Comment: Стандарт подразумевает, что ключи имеют права идти в любом порядке. Если поля в форме например должны идти в определенном порядке, значит в описании формы должна явно содержаться эта информация, например в виде массива с перечисленными именами полей в нужном порядке или дополниьельное поле содержащее порядковый номер данного поля в форме. Все остальное - это не правильное использование формата JSON и попытки такого использования приведут к граблям не только с СУБД но еще много где. библиотека для языка например версию поменяет и отдаст в другом порядке, потому что _имеет полное право_

Comment: *JSON схемы для форм. где конструкция состоит из составления порядка ключей.* Неубедительно. Потому что в таком случае в массиве присутствуют данные, которые не выражены явно, но тем не менее существуют - это именно порядок следования, который по-хорошему должен быть указан явно, например, введением дополнительного числового индекса для сортировки по нему элементов в правильном порядке.

Comment: Т.е вы предлагаете для каждого ключа с объектом задавать доп. параметр например position, который будет указывать на очередь отображения, а там уже переформатировать объект в массив,и сортировать по этому ключу? Как вариант наверное единственный верный, но доп. код.. ( в общем большое Спасибо! Таким образом этот вопрос скорее всего и решу..

Comment: Вам точно надо хранить json как json? Почему не хранить его "как есть" в бинарном виде? Тем более что мускуль не документоориентированная СУБД.

Comment: Хранить json надо как строку, т.к json тут не один, а множество разных, например те же JSON формы могут быть разными по структуре, они хранятся в бд, под определенным ID,и используется или изменяются при нужде..  так-же к этим же формам применяется отдельные опции, как например опции языковых значений, и т.д, и всё это хранится в одном столбце. конечно же предусматривается момент "разделения", это когда данных могут быть много,создается отдельная таблица, по сути примерно по той же структуре..

Comment: @GeorgeKolmer напишите ответ в ответе, а не в вопросе

Answer (score 3):

MySQL хранит JSON в своём внутреннем формате, фактически воссоздавая текстовое представление перед возвращением клиенту:

> JSON documents stored in JSON columns are converted to an internal format that permits quick read access to document elements.

а также

> To make lookups more efficient, it (i.e. MySQL) also sorts the keys of a JSON object.

Так что изменение порядка ключей - это by design. Подробнее см. в [мануале](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Если порядок ключей имеет значение, трудно предложить что-то лучше, чем хранение данных в варчарах. Либо (см. [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)) хранить данные в массиве, который гарантирует порядок элементов:

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans, and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).
>
> ...
>
> An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.

Comment: > "Если порядок ключей имеет значение, трудно предложить что-то лучше, чем хранение данных в варчарах."

дело не только в "хранении", но и в записи определенных частей объекта..при записи или чтении ключи сортируются.. возможен вариант  при котором JSON в определенное место можно записать как "строку", таким образом порядок сохраняется, но теряется доступ к записи определенных частей объекта..

Comment: ЯННП. Количество перечитываний не переходит в качество понимания :(

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответы, очень благодарен!

По моему мнению и как выяснилось другими участниками вопроса,то единственное самое верное решение этой проблемы, заключается в создании дополнительного ключа со значением о позиции объекта, в моем конкретном случае это к примеру имеем такой JSON объект

```
    {
   "value": {
    "pos": 2,
    "type": "string"
   },
   "schema": {
    "pos": 1,
    "type": "string"
   },
   "to_lang": {
    "pos": 3,
    "type": "string"
   }
  }
```

в следствии работы с MySQL JSON(запись,чтение), ключи пересортировываются..
мы храним объект в том же виде, а там где нужна позиция, используем значение **pos**, и переделываем объект в массив. 
в моем случае на Js решил такой функцией

```
        function sortObject(obj) {
        var arr = [];
        var prop;
        for (prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                obj[prop].key = prop;
                arr.push(obj[prop]);
            }
        }
        arr.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.pos - b.pos;
        });
        return arr; // возвращаем массив
    }
```

Конечно если Вы используете готовые решения,как например JSON формы, то придется копать кучу кода, и найти нужное место,чтобы присвоить это изменение, но в принципе у меня получилось решить это буквально за пару минут. 
для тех кто не готов применять изменения, как единственный **альтернативный вариант** где не придется ничего изменять, это сохранение нужной части JSON как "строку", для этого столбец в таблице должен быть в формате LONGTEXT,или в другом формате, исключая JSON, тогда используя функцию MySQL JSON_SET будем записывать значения в JSON как строку, потом естественно декодируем это дело, и получаем сохраненные позиции ключей.. минус данного варианта, что является по сути "костылем", т.к в таком хранении данных, стандартного доступа к ключам строкового объекта не будет.

[Пример записи json как строки sqlFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/84nBFaZXxEtHrXGzzNrh9k/0)